# How to understand Django templates?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, dry

Here is official Django tutorial, templates section:

> First, create a directory called templates in your polls directory. Django will look for templates in there.
>
> Within the templates directory you have just created, create another directory called polls, and within that create a file called index.html. In other words, your template should be at polls/templates/polls/index.html. Because of how the app_directories template loader works as described above, you can refer to this template within Django simply as polls/index.html.

...and explanation of "namespacing":

> Now we might be able to get away with putting our templates directly in polls/templates (rather than creating another polls subdirectory), but it would actually be a bad idea. Django will choose the first template it finds whose name matches, and **if you had a template with the same name in a different application, Django would be unable to distinguish between them.** We need to be able to point Django at the right one, and the easiest way to ensure this is by namespacing them. That is, by putting those templates inside another directory named for the application itself.

but different app has different absolute path of `templates` directory. Is there any problems with such project structure?

```
my_project
    |
    +--first_app
    |       |
    |       +--templates
    |             |
    |             +--index.html
    |             +--foo.html
    +--second_app
            |
            +---templates
                  |
                  +index.html
```

We have my_project/**first_app**/templates/index.html and 
        my_project/**second_app**/templates/index.html - no collision.

> Django will choose the first template it finds whose name matches

I suppose, Django using relative path to compare insted of absolute. What's the point of it? Is there any hidden profits?

I just diving into Django and that seems like violation of `DRY` principle. So, why such elegant and pythonic framework uses such weird convention?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything under `templates/` is grouped into one list. They are "put over one another" in the order of your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting (the bottommost first).

In your case, if `INSTALLED_APPS = ['first_app', 'second_app']`, django will know of two templates:

- `index.html` from first_app, which has overwritten the similary-named one from `second_app`.
- `foo.html` from first_app.

So... everything below `templates/` **in each of your apps** is grouped together. Which is why it is good to use the namespacing mentioned in the docs. So `second_app/templates/second_app/index.html`, for instance.

That Django allows you to overwrite templates is handy: you can overwrite the default login page, for instance.

Comment: `So... everything below templates/ in each of your apps is grouped together.` Why? It is so weird side-effect. If i want to store all(from all apps) my templates together i'd put them in the same folder. Doesn't it looks clearer?

Comment: The idea is that apps are developed separately. You can also re-use existing (open source) apps. With django's template-finding mechanism you can customize those apps' templates.

Comment: I can customize external apps without duplicating folder structure too. Am i wrong?

Comment: *If* you want to customize the `some_other_app/some.html`, you *will* have to create a `yourapp/templates/some_other_app/some.html` file.

Comment: Oh, I still can't understand why do we need to copy folder structure and why storing my separate  files together is better than don't do it(

If i want to customize the `some_other_app/some.html` I will edit this file. Why do i need to avoid it?

Comment: If you *can* edit the template from another app, it means you're editing in downloaded code you normally shouldn't be touching. You ought to just install another app and not touch it. Django is designed for *cleanly* customizing other apps. If you want to do it in a "dirty" way: fine. But keep in mind that django is designed to do it in a clean way.

Comment: All right, I hope it's part of "Django-way" and i just need to get used to it. Thanks for your time.)